Flutter App stuck on splash screen after updating it from Google Play Store
App stuck on splash screen.
I had used these below package:

advanced_rich_text: ^0.0.1+1
cached_network_image: ^3.3.1
carousel_slider: ^4.2.1
cool_alert: ^2.0.1
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
date_picker_plus: ^3.0.2
device_info_plus: ^9.1.2
dio:^5.4.0
dots_indicator: ^3.0.0
dropdown_button2: ^2.3.7
expandable: ^5.0.1
file: ^7.0.0
file_picker: ^6.1.1
file_saver: ^0.2.12
flashy_tab_bar2: ^0.0.6

flutter:   
  sdk: flutter  


flutter_bloc: ^8.1.3
flutter_cached_pdfview: ^0.4.2
flutter_expandable_table: ^2.0.0
flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0
flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.1.1
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0
flutter_svg: ^2.0.10+1
flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.14.11
fluttertoast: ^8.2.4
font_awesome_flutter: ^10.1.0
freezed_annotation: ^2.2.0
get_it: ^7.6.6
go_router: ^13.0.1
google_fonts: ^6.1.0
google_mobile_ads: ^4.0.0
gradient_borders: ^1.0.0
image_picker: ^1.0.7
in_app_review: ^2.0.8
injectable: ^2.3.0
internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
intl: ^0.18.0
json_annotation: ^4.8.1
keyboard_actions: ^4.2.0
loading_animation_widget: ^1.2.0+4

maplibre_gl:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/maplibre/flutter-maplibre-gl.git
    ref: main


mobile_scanner: ^4.0.0
nepali_date_picker: ^6.0.0
nepali_english_calendar: ^1.0.1+1
nepali_utils: ^3.0.4
new_version_plus: ^0.0.11
onesignal_flutter: ^3.0.0
package_info_plus: null
path_provider: ^2.0.11
percent_indicator: ^4.2.3
permission_handler: ^11.1.0
photo_view: ^0.14.0
popup_banner: ^1.0.0
pretty_dio_logger: ^1.3.1
pull_to_refresh: ^2.0.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
shimmer: ^3.0.0
simple_gradient_text: ^1.3.0
table_calendar: ^3.0.5
url_launcher: ^6.2.2
webview_flutter: ^4.4.3
webview_flutter_android: ^3.13.2
webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.10.1

why my app is freezing on splash screen after updating it from playstore?
I added
android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" in androidmanifest.xml file.
But still it stuck on splash screen.
App opens but after clearing cache data from mobile.


Run your app in debug mode and check the Logcat output for any error messages or warnings that might indicate the cause of the issue.
Verify Other Configuration Changes, Splash Screen Implementation and Test on Different Devices also check for Flutter Updates if any.


Usually relative to data local storage, when users update the app, they get your new code, and your new code was changed to the way to use/parse data model from local storage, but the user's data from local storage is still there with old structure/value, which causes exceptions.
You usually do not realize it because, during development, you do a lot of things like clear/remove/logout so you won't get the scenario like real users
A typical example of this issue is that the app works normally after re-install or clear data cache.

If so, how to overcome this?

To find the root cause of this issue:

Install the previous debug version on your device
compile and run your latest version on the device to simulate the update
It should show any error, crash, or warnings in the log. More ever use some analytics tools like firebase etc to log the crashes of live builds.

